# A doubt involving conditional expectation.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

Let $M=(M_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ a martingale with respect to natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_{i}=\sigma(M_j; j \leq i)$. Defines $X_{i}=M_{i}-M_{i-1}$ and, for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

\begin{equation*}
Z_i=X_i{1}_{\{|X_i| > n^{1/3}\}}- \mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{\{|X_i|> n^{1/3}\}}\mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1} \right].
\end{equation*}
I need to show that

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}\left[Z_{i}^{2}\right]  = \mathbb{E}\left[  X_i^{2}{1}_{\{|X_i| > n^{1/3}\}}\right]- \mathbb{E}\left[\left[\mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{\{|X_i|\leq n^{1/3}\}}\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right] \right]^2\right].
\end{equation*}

$\textit{My idea:}$ Writing $A=\{|X_i|> n^{1/3}\}$ to simplify, we have

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[Z_{i}^{2}\right]  = \mathbb{E}\left[  X_i^{2}{1}_{A}\right]-2\mathbb{E}\left[X_i 1_{A}\mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{A}\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right]\right]+ \mathbb{E}\left[\left[\mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{A}\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right] \right]^2\right].
\end{equation}

To conclude the exercise I need to show that

\begin{equation}
-2\mathbb{E}\left[X_i 1_{A}\mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{A}\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right]\right]+ \mathbb{E}\left[\left[\mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{A}\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right] \right]^2\right]
= - \mathbb{E}\left[\left[\mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{A}\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right] \right]^2\right].
\end{equation}

But, for any event $A$, we have

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{A}| \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{A^c}\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right] = - \mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{A^c}\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right],
\end{equation}

since $=\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right] =\mathbb{E}\left[M_{i}-M_{i-1}\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right]= M_{i-1} -M_{i-1}=0$, because $M$ is a martingale. Combining the last two equations, we should have

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[X_i 1_{A}\mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{A}\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right]\right]= \mathbb{E}\left[\left[\mathbb{E}\left[X_i {1}_{A}\mid  \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\right] \right]^2\right].
\end{equation}

Why is this true?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any integrable r.v. $Y$ and any sub-sigma algebra $\mathcal G$ we have  $E[YE(Y|\mathcal G)]=E[E[YE(Y|\mathcal G)]|\mathcal G]=E[E[Y|\mathcal G]E[Y|\mathcal G)]=E[(E(Y|\mathcal G)^{2}]$.

In the first step I used towering property of conditional expectation. In the second step I used the fact that $E[Y|\mathcal G]$ is already $\mathcal G$-measurable so it can be pulled out of the conditional expectation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Kavi.